# where's should i put RDFa Events mark-up?

Tags: html, rdfa

I've decided to include data markup for my events site to make it easier for search engines to use my data. I've decided to go for RDFa over microformats and microdata, however I'm unsure how to best use it...

**my site:**

1 page with a list of events with the essential details for each, each event is clickable taking you to a page with the that events full details.

**the question:**

Which page should i put the RDFa on? I would have gone for each events own page but i'm confused by:

```
  <a href="http://www.example.com/events/spinaltap" rel="v:url" 
     property="v:summary">Spinal Tap</a>
```

do i need to make a link to the events page from itself or do RDFa readers / search engines know to use the current url

i've been using the following RDFa events spec from google webmasters:

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=164506

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding this RDFa markup to the event's detail page, then you could just use something like this:

```
<span resource="http://www.example.com/events/spinaltap" rel="v:url" 
 property="v:summary">Spinal Tap</span>
```

I changed `<a href="...">` to `<span resource="...">`. That's one way of creating a “non-clickable” link that will be visible only to RDFa parsers.

Actually you could just use an empty `resource=""`, because `resource` accepts a relative URL and an empty relative URL expands to the URL of the current page (unless you're doing something funny with `<base>`).

Comment: A complementary answer to that one is available on [Semantic Overflow](http://www.semanticoverflow.com/questions/1157/representing-trips-with-htmlrdfa)